# How to Join the table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin

This is two query that i need to combine:

first query:

```
SELECT emp.name, count(rej.employee_ic) as 'rejected leave'
FROM employee as emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN rejectedleave as rej
ON emp.ic_no = rej.employee_ic
GROUP BY emp.`ic_no`
```

Second query:

```
SELECT emp.name, count(app.employee_ic) as 'approved leave'
FROM employee as emp
LEFT OUTER JOIN approvedleave as app
ON emp.ic_no = app.employee_ic
GROUP BY emp.`ic_no`
```

The output:

first query:
[first query output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV5gs.jpg)

second query:
[second query output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV8bh.jpg)

i want to combine this two table into one table. please help me to solve this problem, appreciate your help.

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and desired results.  It is not obvious what "combine" means in this case.

Comment: Please add desired output in the question

Comment: i want the rejected leave column combine to the second query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you need? It find the count of approved and rejected leaves for each available employee in separate subqueries and then joins it with the employee table to show the count of rejected and approved leaves for each employee in one row.

Use `coalesce(col,0)` to return 0 if the count if null.
Coalesce returns first non null value from the given list of arguments.

```
select
    t1.*,
    coalesce(t2.approvedleave,0) approvedleave
    coalesce(t3.rejectedleave,0) rejectedleave
from employee t1
left join (
    select employee_ic, count(*) approvedleave
    from approvedleave
    group by employee_ic
) t2 on t1.ic_no = t2.employee_ic
left join ( 
    select employee_ic, count(*) rejectedleave
    from rejectedleave
    group by employee_ic
) t3 on t1.ic_no = t3.employee_ic;
```

Read about coalesce here:

- http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php

Comment: i already get the output i need but how to replace the NULL value with 0?

Comment: Use `COALESCE` for that.Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want this:

```
SELECT e.name, COALESCE(r.rejected_leave, 0) as rejected_leave,
       COALESCE(a.approved_leave, 0) as approved_leave
FROM employee e LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT rl.employee_ic, COUNT(*) as rejected_leave
      FROM rejectedleave rl
      GROUP BY rl.employee_ic
     ) r
     ON e.ic_no = r.employee_ic LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT al.employee_ic, COUNT(*) as approved_leave
      FROM approvedleave al
      GROUP BY al.employee_ic
     ) a
     ON e.ic_no = a.employee_ic;
```

That is, do the aggregation *before* doing the joins.  This assumes that `e.ic_no` and `e.name` are both unique in the employees table.

Comment: i already get the output i need but how to replace the NULL value with 0?

Comment: @ShahRezza . . . Use `coalesce()`.  I modified the answer.

Comment: thank you so much @GordonLinoff but can i know the function of coalesce() more detail? because in class i did not learn about that. its good if you can give a link